# SPARK Functional-Correctness Proof

Tags: ada, proof-of-correctness, gnatprove

This [post](https://forum.ada-lang.io/t/spark-proof-title-padded-to-meet-minimum-length-requirement/498) doesn't seem to be getting much attention, so I thought I'd ask again here.

What is it about the type CR that causes this? How can the postcondition be modified to allow SPARK to prove this?

And why do I need to enter at least 220 characters?

Comment: So, what level of proof was requested? Did increasing the level (controlled by the `--level` argument) to 1 or 2 not help? Maybe also mention the versions of GNAT and GNATprove being used. As of release 13, the formal container libraries are no longer shipped with GNAT FSF; They've been moved into a separate library called [SPARKlib](https://github.com/AdaCore/SPARKlib) (though that library cannot be used with any current FSF version of GNATprove as it depends on features that are not yet available in those FSF versions).

Comment: I was proving this withno level specified.Using --level=1 proves this. I think I'll use level 4 and all provers as I proceed. Also, thanks for the information about the formal containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the comments, using `--level=1` proves this.